# C# '+=' Operator

Tags: c#

I have some code that contains the operator '+='.

Specifically, the code reads as follows:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> row in connectionOpts)
            {
                str += String.Format("{0}={1}; ", row.Key, row.Value);
            }
```

What function does this operator perform?

Comment: What do you mean by _What function does this operator perform_? `x += y` is equal to `x = x + y`. Take a look [+= Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx)

Comment: Also, have a look at using a `StringBuilder` instead instead of concatenating the strings (strings are immutable so you are allocating a lot of unneeded memory).

Answer (score 2):

It is an assignment operator.  It adds right operand to the left operand and assigns the result to left operand.

You may want read few [tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_operators.htm), so you can gain better understanding of c# fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

It adds two strings(or ints etc) together.

```
String a = "Hello";
a += " World";
```

String a now = `"Hello World"`

```
int i = 0;
i += 2;
```

int I now = `2`